# Local stripe Webhook not triggering in my Node server

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, webhooks

Been at this for a little while and I'm not sure what I'm missing here. So I've downloaded the stripe CLI and I'm triggering a response with the following command that I want my webhook to respond to

`stripe trigger payment_intent.succeeded`

In the dashboard of my Stripe account I see the test charge.
[image]

Here is where I've set my webhook to point to.

[image]

In postman, when I hit the following URL it successfully get to the server and logs a console statement, even if the request is bad so I know this is the right path.
[image]

My Endpoint Secret and stripe secret should be fine, so I'm currently at a loss for why it doesn't trigger the webhook when running that command from a separate terminal from where my server is hosted. I can attach my code if neccesary.

Comment: Did you launch the listen command: $ stripe listen --skip-verify --forward-to https://localhost:[port]/path_to_webhook ?

Comment: I was following the direction I found here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/webhooks/create?endpoint_location=local

I ran stripe listen --forward-to localhost:8000/webhook

Comment: Aren't you suppoed to set it to the right route ? localhost:8000/api/payments/webhook ?

Comment: yeah, that's what it's set to localhost:8000/api/payments/webhook. Just didn't type it right there

Comment: try to resend an event instead of triggering on: "stripe events resend evt_1Nh..blablabla", and don't forget to login: stripe login

Answer (score 0):

Check your Event Dashboard (i.e., https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/events/evt_XXX) and look for the Webhook Attempts section. You can click on it to see the details about why a webhook delivery fails. If you don't see attempts or need help to trouble delivery failure, you should reach out to Stripe support https://support.stripe.com/contact/email